# Override methods in interactive mode of console?

Tags: python-3.x

I have the code:

```
class Product:
    def __init__(self,name, price,discount):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.discount = discount

    def get_discount_amout(self):
        return self.price * self.discount
```

I copied the code to IPython console and create an instance:

```
In [2]: book = Product('Think Python', 12.99, 30)
```

Calculate the discount amount

```
In [5]: book.get_discount_amout()
Out[5]: 389.7
```

I find the spelling error and arithmetic error,immediately to correct them in the console.
Firstly I define a correct `get_discount_amount` function.

```
def get_discount_amount_correct(self):
    return self.price * self.discount/100
```

Second to overwrite `book`s previous method.

```
book.get_discount_amount = get_discount_amount_correct
```

Test it.

```
In [13]: book.get_discount_amount
Out[13]: <function __main__.get_discount_amount_correct>
```

Fantastic...then

```
In [14]: book.get_discount_amount()
TypeError: get_discount_amount_correct() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

try,

```
In [15]: book.get_discount_amount(self)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

alternatively try lambda:

```
In [16]: book.get_discount_amount = lambda self: self.price * self.discount/100
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

In console, object's attributes can be easily overwrited,
How to overwrite its methods?

Comment: You need to add the corrected method to the class (`Product`), not the instance (`book`).

Comment: it can be modified in script_mode.errors reports in console,`Product.get_discount_amount = get_discount_amount_correct`, `In [26]: Product.get_discount_amount
Out[26]: <function __main__.get_discount_amount_correct>
` @jasonharper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

Keep replacing the method for the **instance**, not the **type** and pass `book` as `self`:

```
book.get_discount_amount(book)
```

**Option 2**

Replace the method for the **type**:

```
Product.get_discount_amount = get_discount_amount_correct
```

And then every new `Product` you create will use the replaced method:

```
new_book = Product('New book', 20, 10)
new_book.get_discount_amount() # prints 2
```